# carbondesignsystem TableSelectRow bing check state in react js

Tags: reactjs, datatable, carbon-design-system

i am using carbon design system with react
i need control Ceheck state of TableSelectRow. how can i do bind selected row to the datatable

```
<TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row) => (
                      <TableRow key={row.id}>
                        <TableSelectRow
             
                          {...getSelectionProps({
                            row,
                            onClick: () => setRowData(row),
                          })}
                        />
                        {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                          <TableCell key={cell.id}>{cell.value}</TableCell>
                        ))}
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </TableBody>
```

Comment: Please be more specific what you have done and in what case you face an error

Comment: normally when screen render and then json data list bind to the carbon datatable, as u can see m code. i am using TableSelectRow so grid has checkbox. normally, i can check of the tables rows and then take in the state.  so, when page render again, table rows should be selected.